# Rule tables to avoiding nested ifelse statements

Tags: r

Idea is to have manageable approach to define rules from some table:

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(rule = c("rule1", "rule2", "rule3"),
                bool = c(T,T,F))

a
#     rule  bool
# 1: rule1  TRUE
# 2: rule2  TRUE
# 3: rule3 FALSE

ifelse(a[rule == "rule1", bool] & a[rule == "rule2", bool] & a[rule == "rule3", bool], 1,
       ifelse(a[rule == "rule1", bool] & a[rule == "rule2", bool], 2,
              ifelse(a[rule == "rule2", bool] & a[rule == "rule3", bool], 3, 4)))
# [1] 2
```

Obviously this is not very sustainable or readable as I keep adding rules.
What would an alternative to `ifelse` here?

Comment: `case_when()` from `dplyr` could be better for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem, in particular as the conditions do not always involve all rows of `a`, i.e., `rule1`, `rule2`, and `rule3`.

I have tried to find a general solution which can be expanded for an arbitrary number of conditions as well as for additional rows in `a`.

The main idea is to replace the conditions in the nested `ifelse()` or `case_when()` statements, resp., by a `data.table` which then can be joined with `a` somehow:

```
library(data.table)
b <- fread(
"rule1, rule2, rule3, result
TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  1
TRUE,  TRUE,  NA,    2
NA,    TRUE,  TRUE,  3
NA,    NA,    NA,    4"
)
```

E.g., the condition in row 2 specifies to return `2` if `rule1` and `rule2` both are `TRUE` while the value of `rule3` does not matter and can be ignored as a *wildcard*.

It is important to note that the order of conditions matters: First, the conditions without any *wildcard* must be checked. Then, the conditions with one *wildcard*, and so on. Finally, if no other match is found the default value is applied (all *wildcards*). The default value must always be given in the last row.
*So, the most specialised conditions come first and the most general last.*

The OP already has given the test data `a` in long format:

> ```
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1  TRUE
> 2: rule2  TRUE
> 3: rule3 FALSE
> ```

Therefore, also the conditions `b` are reshaped to long format:

```
lb <- melt(b[, id := .I], c("id", "result"), variable.name = "rule", value.name = "bool", na.rm = TRUE)[
  , nr := .N, by = id][]

lb
```

> ```
>    id result  rule bool nr
> 1:  1      1 rule1 TRUE  3
> 2:  2      2 rule1 TRUE  2
> 3:  1      1 rule2 TRUE  3
> 4:  2      2 rule2 TRUE  2
> 5:  3      3 rule2 TRUE  2
> 6:  1      1 rule3 TRUE  3
> 7:  3      3 rule3 TRUE  2
> ```

Before reshaping, a row `id` has been added which indicates the order of conditions. *Wildcards* are omitted from the long format as they are not needed for the joins. After reshaping, the number of remaining rows `nr` per `id` is appended, i.e.,  the number of non-wildcard entries.

Now, the conditions are tested:

```
answer <- lb[a, on = .(rule, bool), nomatch = 0L][
  , result[nr == .N], by = .(nr, id)][
    order(-nr, id), first(V1)]
if (length(answer) == 0L) answer <- b[id == max(id), result] # default
answer
```

This happens in four steps:

1. `a` and `lb` are joined (inner join) on `rule` and `bool`,
2. as the data to join are in long format, incomplete conditions are removed by checking the number of conditions for each `id` (`nr` is included in the `by =` clause just for convenience as it is required in the next step),
3. The remaining rows are ordered to pick the first `result` from the most specialised condition,
4. If above operation does not return an `answer`, the default value is returned.

For the given `a`, above code returns

```
answer
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

#### More test cases

To verify above code is working correctly, a more thorough test is required

```
test <- CJ(rule1 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule2 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule3 = c(TRUE, FALSE), sorted = FALSE)
test
```

> ```
>    rule1 rule2 rule3
> 1:  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 2:  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 3:  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> 4:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 5: FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> 6: FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 7: FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> 8: FALSE FALSE FALSE
> ```

Each row represents a version of `a` which is turned into OP's long format by

```
a <- melt(test[i], measure.vars = patterns("^rule"), variable.name = "rule", value.name = "bool")
```

By looping over `i`, all possible combinations of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values can be tested. In addition some intermediate results are printed which help to understand the workings:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used here to improve readability
test <- CJ(rule1 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule2 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule3 = c(TRUE, FALSE), sorted = FALSE)
for (i in seq(nrow(test))) {
  cat("test case", i, "\n")
  a <- melt(test[i], measure.vars = patterns("^rule"), variable.name = "rule", value.name = "bool") %T>% 
    print()
  lb[a, on = .(rule, bool), nomatch = 0L][, result[nr == .N], keyby = .(nr, id)] %>% 
    unique() %>%
    print() # intermediate result printed for illustration
  answer <- lb[a, on = .(rule, bool), nomatch = 0L][
    , result[nr == .N], by = .(nr, id)][
      order(-nr, id), first(V1)]
  if (length(answer) == 0L) answer <- b[id == max(id), result] # default from b
  cat("answer = ", answer, "\n\n")
}
```

> ```
> test case 1 
>     rule bool
> 1: rule1 TRUE
> 2: rule2 TRUE
> 3: rule3 TRUE
>    nr id V1
> 1:  2  2  2
> 2:  2  3  3
> 3:  3  1  1
> answer =  1 
>
> test case 2 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1  TRUE
> 2: rule2  TRUE
> 3: rule3 FALSE
>    nr id V1
> 1:  2  2  2
> answer =  2 
>
> test case 3 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1  TRUE
> 2: rule2 FALSE
> 3: rule3  TRUE
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): nr,id,V1
> answer =  4 
>
> test case 4 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1  TRUE
> 2: rule2 FALSE
> 3: rule3 FALSE
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): nr,id,V1
> answer =  4 
>
> test case 5 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1 FALSE
> 2: rule2  TRUE
> 3: rule3  TRUE
>    nr id V1
> 1:  2  3  3
> answer =  3 
>
> test case 6 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1 FALSE
> 2: rule2  TRUE
> 3: rule3 FALSE
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): nr,id,V1
> answer =  4 
>
> test case 7 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1 FALSE
> 2: rule2 FALSE
> 3: rule3  TRUE
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): nr,id,V1
> answer =  4 
>
> test case 8 
>     rule  bool
> 1: rule1 FALSE
> 2: rule2 FALSE
> 3: rule3 FALSE
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): nr,id,V1
> answer =  4
> ```

As can be seen from the answers, the given conditions are all met.

Test case 1 is worth a closer look. Here, the conditions `id` 1, 2, and 3 may be applicable but condition 1 precedes the other ones as it is the most specialised.

#### Expanding

This is to show that the solution can be expanded for more rules in `a` as well as for more conditions in `b`.

Here is an example with 7 conditions and 4 rule columns.

```
b4 <- fread(
  "rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, result
TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  1
TRUE,  TRUE,  NA,    NA,    2
NA,    TRUE,  TRUE,  NA,    3
NA,    FALSE, NA,    NA,    5
TRUE,  FALSE, NA,    NA,    6
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE,    7
NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    4"
)
```

The test code has been simplified to allow for a more compact view of the 16 text cases:

```
lb <- melt(b4[, id := .I], c("id", "result"), variable.name = "rule", value.name = "bool", na.rm = TRUE)[, nr := .N, by = id][]
test <- CJ(rule1 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule2 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule3 = c(TRUE, FALSE), rule4 = c(TRUE, FALSE), sorted = FALSE)
sapply(
  seq(nrow(test)), 
  function(i) {
    a <- melt(test[i], measure.vars = patterns("^rule"), variable.name = "rule", value.name = "bool")
    answer <- lb[a, on = .(rule, bool), nomatch = 0L][, result[nr == .N], by = .(nr, id)][order(-nr, id), first(V1)]
    if (length(answer) == 0L) answer <- b4[id == max(id), result] # default from b
    return(answer)
  }
) %>% 
  cbind(test, .) %>% 
  setnames(".", "result") %>% 
  print()
```

It returns the table of test cases, i.e., different cases of `a` in wide format, with the result appended:

> ```
>     rule1 rule2 rule3 rule4 result
>  1:  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      1
>  2:  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      2
>  3:  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      2
>  4:  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE      2
>  5:  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE      6
>  6:  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE      6
>  7:  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      6
>  8:  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE      6
>  9: FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      3
> 10: FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      3
> 11: FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      4
> 12: FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE      4
> 13: FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE      5
> 14: FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE      7
> 15: FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      5
> 16: FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE      7
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, based on comment from @tmfmnk:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

a <- data.table(rule = c("rule1", "rule2", "rule3"),
                bool = c(F,T,T))

case_when(a[(bool), identical(rule, c("rule1", "rule2", "rule3"))] ~ 1,
          a[(bool), identical(rule, c("rule1", "rule2"))] ~ 2,
          a[(bool), identical(rule, c("rule2", "rule3"))] ~ 3,
          TRUE ~ 4)
```